# fastest way to initialize a template 2D std:array to 0

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, stl, initialization

I have a templated 2d array `std::array< std::array<ScalarType ,3> ,3 > my_array` and I want to set them all to zero at different times in the program. It seems like I can use `std::array::fill` but

```
my_array.fill(0);
```

Is not working. How do I fill the 2d array properly?

Comment: I'd be inclined to create a `const` array object that holds all zeros, and just copy that over your array whenever you need to zero it. I'd probably name that array object `zero`.

Comment: Whenever you say "not working" you should substantiate that by posting compiler error messages or a description of what goes wrong at run-time. Just saying "not working" is useless - it could mean *anything*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using

```
my_array.fill({});
```

The `{}` in the argument creates a zero-initialized `std::array<ScalarType, 3>`, which is used to fill up the contents of `my_array`.

Comment: thanks, you answer solved my problem! Where can I read up more about this syntax?

Comment: @SunnyIsaLearner, lookup value initialization on the web. You can get started at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization.

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
my_array.fill(0);
```

to this:

```
my_array.fill({});
```

which default initializes the contents of your array.